Can a stream of consciousness be successfully maintained in the first person in a long novel?
I think there are stream of consciousness writings in the third person, but was wondering about the first person. No other dialogue with other characters, just the thoughts of the protagonist as he/she experiences events, interacts with other characters, and encounters fate.
Could interest be maintained without other characters expressing their views, reasons, instructions, feelings? Or is this a stretch? Would this be a unique innovation, or have other authors already ventured in here (where angels fear to tread)?
I realize that the main character would have to be a very interesting soul, with unique personality traits, mysterious and perhaps quixotic undertones, unpredictable tendencies. And the setting, environment, supporting characters, and story would have to be exceptionally picturesque, interesting, and enticing to the senses of the reader.

You mean stream of consciousness.

Why would a stream of consciousness narrative not contain dialogue? We perceive the speech of others just as we perceive other aspects of the world. It is directly represented in our consciousness. It would be utterly strange to show what a person sees, smells, and hears, only not what other people say. Maybe you could give a brief example of how you intend to write this? Just a sentence or a short paragraph, so we know what it is that you are asking about.

@Ben - Thank you for edit! Incorporating dialogue of characters would be the usual practice as in other novels. This approach  of just the thoughts of the protagonist would be unique...a step beyond the usual crowd.---My uncle was deaf, and would see other people in the distance talking.  This caused his mind to think of an array of emotional responses: Were they talking about him?,  Something important he should also know about? Were they plotting a...? etc.  The protagonist's thoughts, resulting actions, or reactions, would be a vast play field for suspicion, suspense, intrigue, resignation.

I see. I believe that the answer to your question is a matter of opinion and conjecture. You'll need to try it to find out. I think it can be a worthwhile experiment, and if nothing else you'll at least learn a lot through it.

I'll point you to my favourite question and answer on this site:

Q: I want to write a novel about [something or other] and now I wonder if it is possible to do [this or that].
A: You can write anything you please.

What you suggest seems both interesting and exceptional and I can well imagine a story written in that way. I am sure it will succeed on the literary level: It will be a functioning narrative that can be read and appreciated. Whether this kind of writing will be commercially successful, though, is difficult to predict. Too many factors play into that.
In general, popular fiction is commonly written in an accessible, simple style, and any deviation from that will reduce your readership. Experimental prose may achieve the admiration of critics and scholars of literature, but if it doesn't become required reading for pupils the number of sales will usually remain low.
If you want to attempt this, I recommend that you study some examples of stream of consciousness writing. As always, the Wikipedia article is a good starting point.
